# Inplace operation error in control problem

Tags: python, pytorch, backpropagation, autograd

I'm new to pytorch and I'm having a problem with some code to train a a neural network to solve a control problem. I use the following code to solve a toy version of my problem:

```py
# SOME IMPORTS
import torch
import torch.autograd as autograd  
from torch import Tensor               
import torch.nn as nn                   
import torch.optim as optim       

# Device configuration
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')


# PARAMETERS OF THE PROBLEM
layers = [4, 32, 32, 4]  # Layers of the NN
steps = 10000  # Simulation steps
train_step = 1  # I train the NN for 1 epoch every train_step steps
lr = 1e-3  # Learning rate
```

After this I define a very simple network:

```py
# DEFINITION OF THE NETWORK (A SIMPLE FEED FORWARD)

class FCN(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self,layers):
        super(FCN, self).__init__() #call __init__ from parent class 
         
        self.linears = []
        for i in range(len(layers)-2):
            self.linears.append(
                nn.Linear(layers[i], layers[i+1])
            )
            self.linears.append(
                nn.ReLU()
            )
            
        self.linears.append(
                nn.Linear(layers[-2], layers[-1])
        )
        
        self.linear_stack = nn.Sequential(*self.linears)
            
    'forward pass'
    def forward(self,x):
        
        out = self.linear_stack(x)

        return out
```

I then use the defined class to create my model:

```py
model = FCN(layers)
model.to(device)
params = list(model.parameters())
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=lr,amsgrad=False)
```

Then I define the loss function and the simulation function, i.e. the function that updates the state of my problem.

```py
def simulate(state_old, model):

    state_new = model(state_old)

    return state_new

def lossNN(state_old,state_new, model):

    error = torch.sum( (state_old-state_new)**2 )

    return error
```

And finally I train my model:

```py
torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)

state_old = torch.Tensor([0.01, 0.01, 0.5, 0.1]).to(device)

for i in range(steps):
    state_new = simulate(state_old, model)
    
    if i%train_step == 0:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = lossNN(state_old, state_new, model)
        loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        optimizer.step()
        
    state_old = state_new
    
    
    if (i%1000)==0:
        print(loss)
        print(state_new)
```

I then get the following error. [Here](https://pastebin.com/ECGXfeiN) you can find the backtrace :

RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [32, 4]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use detach to remove the gradient created in the previous state.

```py
state_old = state_new
```

```py
state_old = state_new.detach()
```

Then your training code changes to:

```py
torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)

state_old = torch.Tensor([0.01, 0.01, 0.5, 0.1]).to(device)

for i in range(steps):
    state_new = simulate(state_old, model)

    if i%train_step == 0:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = lossNN(state_old, state_new, model)
        loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        optimizer.step()

    state_old = state_new.detach()
    
    if (i%1000)==0:
        print(loss)
        print(state_new)
```

Answer (score -2):

The error message "one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation" usually occurs when you perform an in-place operation on a tensor that is part of the computation graph for computing gradients. In PyTorch, performing in-place operations directly modifies the tensor without creating a new tensor, which can interfere with the automatic differentiation mechanism used for gradient computation.

To resolve this issue, you have a few options:

> 1. Avoid in-place operations: Instead of modifying tensors in-place, try using operations that create new tensors with the desired
>    modifications. This ensures that the computation graph remains intact.
>    For example, instead of x += 1, you can use x = x + 1 to perform the
>    addition without modifying x in-place.
> 2. Use the out-of-place equivalent: PyTorch often provides both in-place and out-of-place versions of operations. For example,
>    x.add_(1) is an in-place addition, while torch.add(x, 1) is an
>    out-of-place addition. You can use the out-of-place version to avoid
>    modifying tensors in-place.
> 3. Detach the tensor: If you need to perform an in-place operation on a tensor but don't require its gradients, you can detach the tensor
>    before the operation. This creates a new tensor that shares the same
>    data but is not part of the computation graph. You can detach a tensor
>    using the .detach() method or by wrapping it with torch.no_grad()
>    context.

Remember to carefully review your code and ensure that you're not unknowingly modifying tensors in-place when using operations that require gradients.